# Problems with scanner

Tags: java

I have a problem with my scanner and nextLine. What happens is that it skips the first lap of the loop. My guess is that the scanner already contains something here, like a line break or something. It did work if I used two different scanners for the strCount and the one in the loop. Is this right and if it is, is there any way I can make this work without using two different scanners.

```
import java.util.*;

public class chars_in_string {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Number of strings?");
    int strCount = key.nextInt();
    String [] array = new String[strCount];

    for(int x = 0; x < strCount; x++){

        System.out.print("String "+(x+1)+":");
        array[x] = key.nextLine();

    }
}

}
```

Example of the input/output:

Number of strings? 8

String 1:String 2:

From here it works fine to enter any string and it will just jump 1 step in the loop to get the next one.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `Scanner.nextInt()` does not consume the line terminator. Just do an extra `nextLine()` before entering the loop.

Comment: @user2225454, if this fixed your problem, you should accept Ted's solution as correct (click the check mark)